# Magento 2: How to add where clause in grid collection

Tags: magento2, collection, grid

I am working on a module, where I have 2 custom tables. One is of all customer who have added product to **First table**(one customer can add multiple tables) and that first table is displayed on grid.

On grid action I have a action column which has to show all products added added by a customer.

**My frist tables  structure( table name->rfq)**

[image: frist table]

**my second tables structure (table name->rfqitem)**
[image: second table]

this code gives output  like below

```
    protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();

    $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('rfq')],
        'main_table.rfq_id = secondTable.customer_id', 
        array('main_table.product_id','main_table.qty')
    );
}
```

**current output**
[image: getting]

**but i expect result like this**
[image: expect]
So how can achieve this.

thanks

Comment: Share your code what you have tried. So i can check.

Comment: please check my updated Questin

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add where clause in joinLeft() query :

```
$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('rfq')],
        'main_table.rfq_id = secondTable.customer_id', 
        array('main_table.product_id','main_table.qty')
    )->where("main_table.id IS NOT null");
```

Comment: Item (Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document) with the same ID "2" already exists. This error is raised

Comment: Use ->group("main_table.id"); after where()

Comment: Please upvote again :)

Comment: how it can be done using UI component?